# Can't connect my Visual Studio Code to remote ssh Linux server right after upgrade it to 1.75.1

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote-ssh

On my Windows 10 I've been using Visual Studio Code 1.68.1 for a year, connected to a Ubuntu server, and used its Python interpreter. But right after I upgraded to 1.75.1, my connection broke and everything is gone. Remote SSH won't work anymore and gives me this error:

failed to connect to the remote extension host server XHR failed)

Does anyone have the same problem or know how to fix it?

I double checked my connection settings and everything works as expected. I don't think it's the connection/firewall or anything else linked to my connection.
I'd installed Remote-ssh, WSL and Windows-subsystem-to-Linux extension on the old version, but as of now, some extensions that were crucial to remote Linux SSH server don't work after upgrading to 1.75.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I notice you have this tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux], but you don't seem to be using WSL with VSCode here. This seems to be about using the Remote-SSH extension in VSCode to connect to a remote server (not WSL), right? Regardless, can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78107879/edit) to make it more clear? I suggest either removing the WSL tag or explaining how it comes into play here - Thanks!